# MAC M1 - NODE - node_modules/node-expat/build/Release/node_expat.node: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Tags: node.js, node-modules, apple-m1

Im having trouble trying to work with xml2json, depends on node-expat. I tried installing using brew but doesnt exists

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?